# Prove that you can choose $ 2 ^ {k-1} $ numbers from $2^k -1 $ integers so that the sum of them is divisible by $2^{k-1}$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, cardinals

Prove that you can choose  $ 2 ^ {k-1} $ numbers  from $2^k -1 $ integers so that the sum of them is divisible by $2^{k-1}$  .

The work I have done :

I wanted to use strong induction , I presumed the theorem is correct for all numbers less than  $2^k -1 $ in the form of  $2^n -1 $ from there I concluded  you can choose  $2^{k-1} $ numbers from our  $2^k -1 $ numbers and you can write them in the form of $ 2 ^ {k-1} . m $ , the remaining numbers will be $ 2 ^ {k} $- $ 2 ^ {k-1} : { 2 ^ {k-1}  }$ we can write that in the form of $ 2 ^ {k-1} $ too , but at this point I realized I was way off the solution and appreciate any other ideas (even not involving induction)

Comment: Note another duplicate post is [West German Mathematics Olympiad 1981](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2049522/602049). Also, an almost duplicate post is [Prove for any number n, it is possible to select $X = 2^n$ numbers from $2^{n+1}$ numbers s.t. the sum of X is divisible by $2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1496045/602049) (with this one using a set size one larger than yours).

Comment: Do you have any advice for searching these solutions up ?
I cannot find the problems related to my own problem without not posting and hearing other people 's links .

Comment: Thank you for your interest & concern re: searching for existing appropriate posts. My advice is to first read [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265), & possibly also a few other posts linked there in the comments & answers. I don't have much to add except that the built-in search uses "and" between terms, so try to keep the length & number of terms reasonably minimal. Finally, FYI, I was able to come up with the duplicate of your question, & the other $2$ posts, so quickly as they're in my previous [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3754767).